# nagios Missing Dependency: perl(Net::SNMP)

Tags: nagios, centos5, nrpe

I have an odd problem.  I'm trying to install nagios NRPE but it keeps failing with

```
nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Net::SNMP) is needed by package nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
```

The package `1:net-snmp-perl-5.3.2.2-9.el5_5.1.i386` is already installed and latest version.

Thoughts?

The environment is Centos 5.5 with Cpanel 11 installed.

Comment: Is the base nagios package already installed, and from which repository did you install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone else is having issues with this: check your yum exclude list here: /etc/yum.conf

with Cpanel installed lots of packages are getting excluded. So for the one-off install of nagios-nrpe remove perl* from the list of excluded packages, run 'yum install nagios-nrpe.x86_64' and add it back after installation.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `net-snmp-perl` and `perl-Net-SNMP`. They are not the same. The file lists do not overlap.

`perl-Net-SNMP` provides `perl(Net::SNMP)`

Details: `net-snmp-perl` is the perl interface to the net-snmp (aka ucsd snmp) library. `perl-Net-SNMP` is completely independent of (and does not require) the net-snmp library.

Comment: I got that the package perl-Net-SNMP is not available.  I'm using RPMForge is there another repo I should be using?

Comment: @mech-software No, it is in rpmforge: yum info perl-Net-SNMP
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
68 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Available Packages
Name       : perl-Net-SNMP
Arch       : noarch
Version    : 5.2.0
Release    : 1.2.el5.rf
Size       : 96 k
Repo       : rpmforge

Comment: yum repolist | grep rpmforge:
rpmforge               RHEL 5 - RPMforge.net - dag               enabled: 10,152

Answer (score 0):

install it from here

http://packages.sw.be/perl-Net-SNMP/

Comment: This is a dependency nightmare, I cant install that without other modules that are "already" installed.  Can't I update a repo or something and do this with yum?

Answer (score 0):

A summary of the answers here with added commands:

1. With cPanel, remove perl* from exclude in /etc/yum.conf
2. Install perl-Net-SNMP **not** net-snmp-perl (from rpmforge: http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B)
3. Put perl* back in /etc/yum.conf in exclude

Copy paste command line fu:

```
    cp /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum.conf.bak-`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
    sed -i 's/perl\* //g' /etc/yum.conf
    yum install -y perl-Net-SNMP nagios-nrpe
    sed -i 's/php\*/perl\* php\*/g' /etc/yum.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similiar problems:

```
--> Package fping.x86_64 0:2.4b2-7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins = 1.4.15-2.el5 for package: nagios-plugins-load
```

The origin of the problem was an additional package repository, in my case 'Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux'. I have created an extra configuration file /etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo

To check if you have the same problem, execute the following command

```
yum list nagios\*
[...]
* epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
Installed Packages
nagios-plugins.x86_64  1.4.15-2.el5   installed
[...]
Available Packages
nagios-plugins.x86_64  1.4.15-2.el5.rf     dag <-- the additional repository!
[...]
```

The solution is to exclude this package in the dag-repository. You can do this on repository level.

Add the following line to the additional repository configuration file(/etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo):

```
 exclude=nagios*
```

Note: If you want to exclude more packages just add them to the line with a space between different excludes.